# Is an atomic operation enough

Tags: c#

```
class StopIt
{
  private bool stop;

  void Loop()
  {
    while (!stop)
    {
       // work
    }
  }

  void Stop()
  {
    stop = true;
  }
}
```

Basically, if the Loop method is running in one thread and Stop is called from another will the operation stop properly? I understand that bool read/write is atomic. But, is this enough? If the thread loop is not stopped immediately there is trouble. Should I mark stop volatile?

Comment: My rule: if you do not know EXACTLY what volatile means, you should not be attempting to write lock free programs. Since you're asking the question, you do not know what it means. So don't attempt to write a lock-free program. Be safe. Use a lock. Locks are only expensive when contended; don't try to make it lock-free until you are certain that (1) you have a performance problem (2) the lock is the cause of the problem and (3) you understand what volatile means down to the processor hardware level.

Comment: Shouldn't I use lock when stop is accessed? If so, then how do I lock the read access in the while loop?

Comment: @yummy: it's difficult to lock on read as it looks now, since you access the field directly in your while loop. If you encapsulate that read in a property (or a method), you can use a lock for reading the valu.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you should definitely mark `stop` as volatile.

Atomicity isn't enough - it doesn't guarantee that one thread will ever "see" the changes made by another.

While my understanding of `volatile` is currently undergoing some surgery, you can *roughly* think of a write to a volatile variable as "make sure others can see this immediately!" and a read from a volatile variable as "I want to see the latest value!"

Without making `stop` volatile, that loop could go on forever, even if `Stop()` is called in a different thread. Basically the JIT could quite reasonably read the variable into a register and then just read from the register forever.

In fact, if "work" ever involves calling a non-inlined method, I believe the JIT is currently forced to do a volatile read anyway, but that's just a current practical limitation... the *theory* says you should make it volatile.

Comment: The contrary is true too: volatile is not enough for atomicity!

Comment: @Noldorin: Irrelevant in this case, as the write to the boolean *will* be atomic based on section 12.6.6 of ECMA 335 partition 1.

Comment: @WebDevHobo: What do you mean by "one thread access what happens in another"? The two threads will have a shared reference to a StopIt instance, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: You are right - but in the general case, it is true, I'm sure you will admit.

Comment: In the general case you're usually changing more than one variable, at which point atomicity becomes an entirely different matter. However, given that references and most of the primitives *do* allow atomic access, I rarely find that I need to worry about atomicity without *also* worrying about volatility. While they're theoretically somewhat orthogonal, I usually find if I get the volatility right, the rest is fine (for a single value).

Comment: @Jon Skeet: That could be summarised as "yes"... though thanks for clarifying things too.